# Fastest way to copy data from one table to another using linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table on another SQL server which I need to copy from overnight. The structure of the destination table  is very similar so I was just going to use something like the code below.
Source - http://forums.asp.net/t/1322979.aspx/1

I have not tried this yet, but is there a better/quicker way to do this in linq?

```
    //there exist two table list and listSecond
    DataClassesDataContext dataClass = new DataClassesDataContext(); //create the instance of the DataContext

    var str = from a in dataClass.lists select a;
    foreach (var val in str) // iterator the data from the list and insert them into the listSecond
    {
        listSecond ls = new listSecond();
        ls.ID = val.ID;
        ls.pid = val.pid;
        ls.url = val.url;
        dataClass.listSeconds.InsertOnSubmit(ls);

    }
    dataClass.SubmitChanges();
    Response.Write("success");
```

Comment: It's probably quicker to make a stored procedure to insert the results of a select. Not sure what LINQ will do, but you might end up with loads of INSERT... VALUES statements. You could always add the stored procedure to your datacontext.

Comment: Just to add a bit of context in case anyone gets here from google. I was going through a phase of "Stored Procedures bad and LINQ good" which is why I asked the question in the first place. Clearly that was the wrong attitude to have and this is a good example of choosing the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LINQ to insert large amounts of data is not a good idea, except maybe with complicated schemas that need much transformations before being copied. It will create a separate query for each row inserted, in addition to logging them all in the transaction log.

A much faster solution can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlBulkCopy.aspx) - it's using `SqlBulkCopy`, which is a method for inserting large amounts of data in a single query, withouth transaction logging to slow it down. It will be *an order of magnitude* faster, and I'm telling you this from personal experience with both methods.